# Writing to a packaged app folder in Electron

Tags: electron

I'm creating a portable Electron app that writes some files to the program folder. It works pretty well when I package it without the --asar option in Electron-packager, which leaves the resources folder with plain html + js files.

Now when I try to compile it with the --asar option, so that it packages the resources folder into one file, I can't access the program directory any more with the following code:

```
remote.app.getAppPath()
```

This now returns the path of the asar file, so I can't really write to the application folder any more. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot modify the asar of a running Electron app. You should be saving your config outside of the asar path.